# How can I extract the zip file in colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

This is my file;

```
ucf101_jpegs_256.zip.001
```

[image]

I have used this method but it is showing me the error;

```
!unzip ucf101_jpegs_256.zip.001

Archive:  ucf101_jpegs_256.zip.001
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of ucf101_jpegs_256.zip.001 or
        ucf101_jpegs_256.zip.001.zip, and cannot find ucf101_jpegs_256.zip.001.ZIP, period.
```

Comment: Do you have the rest of the fragments of the file? `ucf101_jpegs_256.zip.002`, `ucf101_jpegs_256.zip.003`, and so on...

Comment: The archive seems to consist of multiple files but you only have the first.

Comment: Yes, till ucf101_jpegs_256.zip.003, but only this file 'ucf101_jpegs_256.zip.001' is in my use

Answer (score 3):

1. make sure your zip file is on the root of your drive.
2. First Mount your Google Drive

```py
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Run the below cell to Unzip a .zip file

```py
!unzip "/content/drive/My Drive/ucf101_jpegs_256.zip.001" -d "/content/drive/My Drive/"
```